# functions in modules are not recognized from the first time

Tags: python, performance, function, module

When I imported the whole module it didn't recognize the attribute, but when I imported the attribute only it worked !!
Why this happen and how can I solve it?

[image]

This also happens a lot when using the "Tkinter" module.

Comment: What are the contents of `Bio`?

Comment: What do you mean?
It a library like pandas and random ...

Comment: what is `Bio`? Is it a module you have written? Is it something you installed via `pip`?

Comment: installed via pip

Comment: ....and the pypi link is?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/biopython/

Comment: I don't think it is related to that specific module, because it already happens with other modules as Tkinter

Comment: Modules don't always export all of their classes automatically.